# Android media controller

Tags: android, visibility, mediacontroller

By default the mediacontroller for video view appears only for 3 sec. I want it to be there untill the song is playing. I know I have to use this peice of code: -

```
mediacontrollername.show(0);
```

But apparently it doesn't seems to be doing its job correctly 
What should I do for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223494/android-audio-player-need-help/6223541#6223541

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone searched for this issue and still needs a solution, have a look at this: [MediaController 3 Second Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344600/mediacontroller-3-second-issue/21750446#21750446)