# MediaController 3 Second Issue

Tags: android

I am trying to use a MediaController and alter it so that it does not disappear after 3 seconds. I have found this code in a related question and I am using it:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this) {   
    @Override
    public void hide()
    {
        mediaController.show();
    }
};
```

This code works, but when the activity stops (from using back button), I get log errors about a leaked window from a view added in the code below at the show(0) statement:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.audio_control));

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
        mediaController.show(0);
      }
    });
}
```

It seems to me that overriding the hide method by simply calling the show method means the hide method is not doing what is needed when finishing the activity. I must be overriding other necessary functionality, like actually hiding the controller!

I want to hide the controller when necessary (such as when finishing with it), but not in the case of when it is simply being hidden after 3 seconds (and the activity is not being finished).

Or maybe I should let the controller disappear after 3 seconds all the time but I am not sure I understand why it is implemented this way. It seems better to just keep it there all the time to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the MediaController:

```
private View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void More ...onClick(View v) {
        doPauseResume();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};
```

There are two ways to solve this.

A) Override the `hide()` method:

```
class MyMediaController extends MediaController {
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // Nope, do not hide. Call hideActually() to actually hide. 
    }

    public void hideActually() {
        super.hide();
    }
}
```

B) Override the `show()` methods:

```
class MyMediaController extends MediaController {
    public int mTimeout = 0;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        show(mTimeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        super.show(mTimeout);
    }
}
```

Overriding the `hide()` method gives you the full control over hiding the MediaController, but you have to ensure calling `hideActually()` before the Activity is destroyed, else you'll get these log errors about a leaked window.

Overriding the `show()` methods gives you the chance to set a timeout after all. In this case there are some events on which the MediaController will hide without calling the `hide()` method explicitly, i.e. when the user presses the back button.

**Personally I'd prefer using a mix of both implementations:**

```
class MyMediaController extends MediaController {
    public int mTimeout = 0;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        show(mTimeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        super.show(mTimeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // Do not hide until a timeout is set 
        if (mTimeout > 0) super.hide();
    }

    public void hideActually() {
        super.hide();
    }
}
```

In this case you have full control over showing and hiding the MediaController when `mTimeout = 0`, but you get the "normal" behaviour of the MediaController when you actually set a timeout.